# When axios posting an array of images I am getting a 500 error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, file, axios

Okay so i have some code where an user can upload Images. He can upload a multiple images. The thing is that when the user uploads the pictures and there is a request sent to the server I get a 500 error code.

The code:

```
ChangeImages(images) {
      this.images = images;
      console.log("imagesEmit", this.images);
      console.log(this.step);
      console.log("images", images);
      console.log("thishome", this.home);
      const formData = new FormData();
      let id = this.homeId;

      formData.append(
        "data",
        JSON.stringify({ file: this.images[0], position: 1 })
      );
      console.log(formData);
      axios
        .post(`/api/upload-home-picture/${id}`, formData, {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          this.home.images[0].push(response.data);
        });
    },
```

So here as you see I am sending the request in a listener. I am gonna show the results in console.logs:

this.images:
```"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABsoA…wD3k6myVTczaWMZ5Ebv8P2lNvc037YOAAAAAASUVORK5CYII="`````

this.home:

```
funding_round_end: (...)
funding_round_start: (...)
funding_round_time: (...)
hpi_zip_avg_appreciation: (...)
id: (...)
images: (...)
info: (...)
interest: (...)
invest_now: (...)
```

Also the payload:
`{"images":"data:image/png;base64,`
And the backend code:

```
@bp.route('/upload-home-picture', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def upload_home_picture():
    # TODO test permission
    data = json.loads(request.form['data'])
    home_id = data['home']
    home = UserHome.query.get(home_id)
    url = _upload_file()
    db.session.add(UserHomeImage(url=url, home=home, pos=0))
    db.session.commit()
    result = dict(url=url, pos=0)
    return jsonify(result)
´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to send an image without `JSON.stringify`.

```
onUpload() {      
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.images[0]);
    axios.post(
        `/api/upload-home-picture/${id}`
        ,formData
        ,{headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}}
    )
    .then((response) => {
          this.home.images[0].push(response.data);
    });
    .catch(e => {
       //...
    })
}
```

And it will be easier to get it as a file in Python.